# plus 1 to column each time page viewed?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please help i am trying to make a kind of view count, to reflect the number of times a post has been viewed.

I am trying to create a function in mysql which will add +1 to a column called read in my table. so if the count starts from 0 in the column and each time someone opens that post it adds a 1 and another 1 and another 1 for however many times the page has been accessed.

i am trying to do this but am failing miserably can someone please show me how to achieve this type of thing please.

```
function read_forum_set() {
    global $connection;
    global $forum_id;
    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM ptb_forum, ptb_profiles
            UPDATE ptb_forum.read_forum +1
            WHERE ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_forum.from_user_id
            AND ptb_forum.id = '$forum_id' ";
    $read_forum_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($read_forum_set);
    return $read_forum_set;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix and match your queries. SELECT as one query, UPDATE as a second

Answer (score 0):

You need an update with join:

```
update ptb_forum
join ptb_profiles on ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_forum.from_user_id
set ptb_forum.read_forum = ptb_forum.read_forum + 1
where ptb_forum.id = $forum_id
```

Whatever you do, make sure you use `update ... set column = column + 1` and not two separate queries (one to read the old count and one to update it) because **only with a single update expression you will be sure that each hit is counted exactly once**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's probably better to separate the queries out for sanity sake.

As for an increment query, very simple

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = column + 1
WHERE foo = bar
```